# error: expected ‘{’ before ‘*’ token struct (C programming help)

Tags: c, linked-list

I am getting the following error when I try to compile and run my code. " error: expected ‘{’ before ‘*’ token struct ".

```
    The code it is referring to:

    #ifndef node
    #define node
    struct node
    {
     int datum;
     struct node * next;
    }  ;
   #endif
```

The above code is for a user-defined header file called "node.h". It will be used to create a linked list.

Comment: `#define node` will replace with an empty token wherever there is a `node` after that point. See the problem?

Comment: @kaylum Could you elaborate on your comment? What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: @LoV_a Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I stab a spoon into my eye. What can I do to stop it? Answer: Don't stab yourself with a spoon in your eye. In your ifdef / define use an identifier that isn't used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define node
```

That will replace with an empty token wherever there is a `node` after that point. So after preprocessing the code becomes:

```
struct
{
 int datum;
 struct * next;
}  ;
```

So need to pick a name for the `define` that is not used as an identifier in the file. Commonly the define reflects the file name:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

struct node
{
    int datum;
    struct node * next;
};

#endif
```